# Prove that : $K(\alpha)=K(\alpha^{2})$ , $K$ commutative field

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, galois-extensions

Problem :

Let $K$ be a commutative field, and $\alpha$ an

aldebraic element of $K$ of odd degree.

Proof that  :  $K(\alpha)=K(\alpha^{2})$

My simple try

Since $\alpha$ algebraic in $K$ so

$\exists F(x)=x-\alpha$ such that $d°F≥1$  and

$F(\alpha)=0$

But  I don't know how I complete this work

Please give me ideas or hints to approach it

Answer (score 3):

$[K(\alpha):K(\alpha^2)]\leq 2$ since $X^2-\alpha^2$ has $\alpha$ as a root.  Is $[K(\alpha):K(\alpha^2)]=2$ possible?  (*Hint*: tower-law)

Comment: Sir can u explain why $degree ≤2$

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: @EllenEllen This is because $f = x^2-\alpha^2$ has root $\alpha$ in $K(\alpha^2)$. If $\alpha \in K(\alpha^2)$, the minimal polynomial would simply be $x-\alpha$ with degree 1. Otherwise f would be the minimal polynomial with degree 2.